# ViewHolder failing to create a ListView, Can't store "inflater layout" as part of my ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-viewholder, getview

Below is my attempt to create a list view: this code is for my MainActivity and the app won't work at all. 
I tried to include my Layout inflation to my view holder and that broke everything. I put Both my current code (that does not work) and the last point when it worked (before trying to include Layout to View Holder).
Also this is the only part I changed so the problem IS here .
 **Please** tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Is there a way to include Layout to ViewHolder? ThankYou.

**Updated** code Based on answers (Still doesn't work):

```
 public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    /*using HolderView to reuse view*/
    if (rowView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        //inflating the layout Once and then storing it in rowView for reusing
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_super_class, null);

        // configure view holder and store it for reusing
        viewHolder.largeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
        viewHolder.smallText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }
```

Current (not working) code:

```
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    /*using HolderView to reuse view*/
    if (rowView == null){

        //inflating the layout Once and then storing it in rowView for reusing
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_super_class, null);

        // configure view holder and store it for reusing
        viewHolder.largeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
        viewHolder.smallText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallText);
    }

    /*using if condition to populate each row with correct information*/
    if (i >= 0) {

        viewHolder.largeText.setText(name[i]);
        viewHolder.smallText.setText(quantity[i]);

        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), name[i] + " * " + quantity[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(context, ClassActivity.class);
                goToNextActivity.putExtra("superClass_name", name[i]);
                context.startActivity(goToNextActivity);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

And this is the last point when my app worked without any problem:

```
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    /*using HolderView to reuse view*/

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_super_class, null);

    viewHolder.largeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
    viewHolder.smallText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

    /*using if condition to populate each row with correct information*/
    if (i >= 0) {

        viewHolder.largeText.setText(name[i]);
        viewHolder.smallText.setText(quantity[i]);

        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), name[i] + " * " + quantity[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(context, ClassActivity.class);
                goToNextActivity.putExtra("superClass_name", name[i]);
                context.startActivity(goToNextActivity);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}

/*using viewHolder to cache row view */
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView largeText;
    public TextView smallText;
}
```

I searched for a few hours but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Initialize `viewHolder = new ViewHolder();` when view is null here   `if (rowView == null){`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, using them here is the Answer to my question:
1) needed to initialize my viewHolder Inside if statement.
2) needed to change getView's return from view to rowView.
3) needed to change all mentions of view in my getView to rowView.

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    /*using HolderView to reuse view*/
    if (rowView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        //inflating the layout Once and then storing it in rowView for reusing
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_super_class, null);

        // configure view holder and store it for reusing
        viewHolder.largeText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
        viewHolder.smallText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }

    /*using if condition to populate each row with correct information*/
    if (i >= 0) {

        viewHolder.largeText.setText(name[i]);
        viewHolder.smallText.setText(quantity[i]);

        rowView.setClickable(true);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), name[i] + " * " + quantity[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(context, ClassActivity.class);
                goToNextActivity.putExtra("superClass_name", name[i]);
                context.startActivity(goToNextActivity);
            }
        });
    }
    return rowView;
}

/*using viewHolder to cache row view */
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView largeText;
    public TextView smallText;
}
```